# Expressionengine cron email syntax error

Tags: expressionengine

I am using expression engine 2.4.0 . I have the plugin in a correct directory, but everytimeI put the sample code  it give me  an error

```
{exp:cron plugin="cron_email" day="23" minute="59" to="webmaster@mysite.com" subject="Daily Email"}

Hello There!

{/exp:cron}
```

The following tag has a syntax error:

```
{exp:cron}
```

Please correct the syntax in your template.

Am I doing anything wrong.Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have both the [Cron plugin](https://github.com/EllisLab/Cron) *and* the [Cron Send Email plugin](http://expressionengine.com/downloads/details/cron_send_email/) installed.

Comment: Thanks Derek for your reply. Both of these plugin have same folder name and class name they are overwritten by each other when I try to install it. Can I change the folder and when I install it? Is there any completed step by step example that can help me in better understanding about these plugins.

Comment: The link Derek originally gave on the EE site has an incorrect link to the download. I've amended his link. All add-ons should be installed into the expressionengine/third_party folder, each in their own folders. pi.cron.php should be in a folder called cron and pi.cron_email.php should be in a folder called cron_email.

Comment: https://github.com/EllisLab/Cron-Email for Cron_Email and https://github.com/EllisLab/Cron for Cron. Above links are pointing to the same location. Thanks